# Why is my Scheduled Task not running

Tags: java, timer

I have a scheduled task which takes the hostname and other Calendar information from a JSP page. For the "HOUR_of_Day" input, I always add 12 and pass the total to Calender since it uses a 24 - hour format. What I did worked fine yesterday evening but it is not working this morning. It does not run anymore at the scheduled time. I certainly have done something wrong and need some direction. Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

     String hostname = null; 

     //The default no - arg constructor
     //=============================
     public ScheduledTask(){

     }


     /**
      * Another overloaded constructor
      * that accepts an object
      * @param scanHostObj

    public ScheduledTask(ScanHost scanHostObj){

        hostname = scanHostObj.getHostname();

    }


    /**
     * Another overloaded constructor
     * that accepts a string parameter
     * @param nodename
     */
    public ScheduledTask(String nodename){
       hostname = nodename; 
    }

    /**
     * The run method that executes 
     * the scheduled task
     */
    public void run() {

        new ScanUtility().performHostScan(hostname);

    }


    public void executeScheduledScanJob(ScanHost hostObj, Scheduler schedulerObj){ 

        /**
         * Get the various schedule 
         * data, convert to appropriate data type
         * and feed to calender class
         */
        String nodename = hostObj.getHostname();
        String dayOfScan = schedulerObj.getDayOfScan();
        String hourOfScan = schedulerObj.getHourOfScan();
        String minuteOfScan = schedulerObj.getMinuteofScan();

        //Convert String values to integers
        //===================================
        final int  THE_DAY =  Integer.parseInt(dayOfScan);
        final int  THE_HOUR = Integer.parseInt(hourOfScan);
        final int  REAL_HOUR = THE_HOUR + 12;
        final int  THE_MINUTE = Integer.parseInt(minuteOfScan);

        /**
         * Feed these time values to the Calendar class.
         * Since Calendar takes a 24 - hour format for hours
         * it is better to add 12 to any integer value for
         * hours to bring the real hourly format to the 24
         * format required by the Calendar class
         */
        Calendar scheduleCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,  THE_DAY);
        scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,   REAL_HOUR);
        scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,    THE_MINUTE);


        /**
         * Then Initialize the timer Object
         * and pass in parameters to it method
         * cancel out all tasks/jobs after running them
         */

         Timer scheduledTimeObj = new Timer(); 
         ScheduledTask scheduledTaskObj = new ScheduledTask(nodename);

        scheduledTimeObj.schedule(scheduledTaskObj, scheduleCalendar.getTime());

        scheduledTimeObj.cancel();
        scheduledTaskObj.cancel();

    }




}
```

Comment: Your "*not working*" is not descriptive at all.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No am not getting any errors. It does not run anymore  at the scheduled time

Comment: `REAL_HOUR` is not well calculated. How will you tell apart the 10 AM from the 10 PM?

Comment: I  think Calender does  that automatically if it's a 24 - hour format

Comment: The result:  INFO: The Calendar Hour is  Tue Aug 21 21:40:13 EDT 2018  So am sticking to my implementation

Comment: Nope, it doesn't do that automatically. You need to set AM_PM to AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace

```
  scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,   REAL_HOUR);
```

With this:

```
 scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,   THE_HOUR);
```

This one will take 12 hour format.

Additionally, you can set AM_PM to AM or PM. If you try to parse a PM date, use PM here.

```
scheduleCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,   Calendar.PM);
```

Comment: Thank you for  your response. I have  tried that but my problem is differentiating between PM and AM

Comment: Thank you, I will try your  suggestion and  get back

Comment: Thank  You Tobias for all your suggestions.  Am sticking to my  earlier implementation of using  a 24 - hour format.   Below is what  I get:  INFO: The Calendar Hour isTue Aug 21 21:40:13 EDT 2018

Comment: Well, your earlier Implementation doesn't work, does it? I can't tell what is wrong from your pasted line.  You should post the expected versus the actual result, together with the input variables.

Comment: The  expected result is for it to kick in at the scheduled time and run a scan.  It worked on Sunday but stopped working yesterday.  This morning it worked when I  replace the calendar.getTime() with a zero like this:   scheduledTimerObj.schedule(new ScheduledTask(nodename), 0);  .  Now that also wouldn't start the task. So it is certain there is something else causing my task not to kick in.

Comment: I just found out that scheduledTimerObj.cancel() stops the task from executing. It works if I  refrain from overriding the cancel()  method.